# Binance API proper way to open a futures trade?

Tags: python, api, binance

I am currently in the midst of writing myself a little python bot for binance using their API and I find the documentation rather lackluster and wondered whether someone on here might be able to help.

Let's say I want to open up a futures trade in the BTCUSDT pairing with a leverage of 5x and a margin of 100 USDT at market price, with a take profit at 50% and a stop loss at 10%.

```
from binance.client import Client
import cfg
client = Client(cfg.api_key, cfg.api_secret)
client.futures_create_order(symbol='BNBUSDT', side='LONG', type='MARKET',  quantity = 100 USDT * leverage / asset_price)
```

This is about as far as I get. I don't see any leverage attribute, however there is another function called
`futures_change_leverage()`
which is able to change your leverage, so I do have to initialize a position and then change the leverage? Wouldn't that also just scale my margin down?

I am also rather lost as to how the later attributes work and how I would be able to place a take profit and stop loss order.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

From running a few tests it seems like Binance uses the margin type (cross or isolated) and the leverage you last used on that pairing on the web, desktop or mobile app. If you have not changed it, it defaults to 20x Cross.

So before opening a futures trade you should change the leverage and margin type and only then open the position.

For example:

```
client.futures_change_margin_type(symbol='BNBUSDT', marginType='ISOLATED')
```

marginType has to be either 'ISOLATED' or 'CROSSED'.

Since questions came up about leverage and margin types and how to set those:

```
def adjust_leverage(symbol, client):
    client.futures_change_leverage(symbol=symbol, leverage=10)

def adjust_margintype(symbol, client):
    client.futures_change_margin_type(symbol=symbol, marginType='ISOLATED')
```

I am still figuring out how to do Stop Losses and Take Profits, potentially even Trailing SL, if I do find them I will keep you posted.

Comment: Can you please explain why did you take the line of code that sets the leverage from the answer?

Comment: Hi. It works fine for setting the margin type, however it still doesn't work for setting the leverage.

Comment: @JaquelinePassos cause margin type is set separetely for each symbol and not included in the opening of the trade itself

Comment: Setting leverage the way you did above doesn't seem to work for me, at least within binance-futures testnet. Orders are always executed with the leverage indicated on the platform

Answer (score 2):

If anyone searching for it in mid-2023.

To fully answer a question, using the newest Binance's library 'binance.um_futures':

First, you need to set leverage for the symbol, let's say BTCUSDT:

```
client.change_leverage(symbol="BTCUSDT", leverage=5, recvWindow = 60000)
```

Next, opening initial position:
First, calculate the quantity for 100 USDT with the formula:

> quantity = 100 USDT * 5 leverage / BTCUSDT_current_price

```
initial_position = client.new_order(
        symbol="BTCUSDT", 
        side="BUY",
        type=order_type,
        quantity=quantity,
        timestamp = timestamp,
        recvWindow = 60000
    )
```

Next, to actually set Take Profit and Stop Loss, you need to send 2 separate orders with opposite sides:

Take Profit example:
You need to calculate 50% ROE% with the formula:

```
def calculate_tpsl(symbol, side, leverage, tp_percentage=take_profit_percentage, sl_percentage=stop_loss_percentage):
    def calculate_target_price(roe):
        if side == "SELL":
            sltp_target_price = entry_price / (1 - roe / leverage)
        
        else:
            sltp_target_price = entry_price * (1 + roe / leverage)
            
        return sltp_target_price

    
    if side == "BUY":
        profit_perc = tp_percentage / 100
        profit_mark_price = calculate_target_price(profit_perc)

        loss_perc = -sl_percentage / 100
        loss_mark_price = calculate_target_price(loss_perc)
    
    if side == "SELL":
        profit_perc = -tp_percentage / 100
        profit_mark_price = calculate_target_price(profit_perc)

        loss_perc = sl_percentage / 100
        loss_mark_price = calculate_target_price(loss_perc)

    return profit_mark_price, loss_mark_price
```

Send Take Profit Position:

```
take_profit_position = client.new_order(
            symbol="BTCUSDT",
            side="SELL",
            type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET",
            quantity=quantity,
            stopPrice=take_profit_price,
            timeInForce="GTE_GTC",
            reduceOnly="True",
            timestamp = timestamp,
            recvWindow = 60000
        )
```

and you can do the same to stop loss, make type: STOP_MARKET

Hope that answers your question in detail.

Answer (score -1):

this is how I'm doing the Close position.

```
Par = clientR.futures_symbol_ticker(Symbol=ticker)

def CLOSE_POSITIONLONG(ticker):

      par = client.futures_symbol_ticker(Symbol=ticker)
      preciodeventa = float(par.get('price'))
      print("Precio de cierre: " + str(preciodeventa))
      triggerB = float(preciodeventa)+(float(preciodeventa)*0.0005)
      client.futures_create_order(
      symbol = ticker
      ,side='SELL'
      ,closePosition=True
      ,stopPrice= round(triggerB,3)
      ,type='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET'
      )

      triggerS = float(preciodeventa)-(float(preciodeventa)*0.0005)
      client.futures_create_order(
      symbol = ticker
      ,side='SELL'
      ,closePosition=True
      ,stopPrice= round(triggerS,3)
      ,type='STOP_MARKET'
      )
```

Comment: Please be sure to write answers in English.